# Removes lines from xml file that match lines from a list

Tags: powershell

I can't seems to figure out how to loop through an xml file and remove an entire "`<option></option>`" block that matches a lines from list.  I know I need to loop through the xml file, then loop through the list. In the end I would replace the contents for the xml with the "filtered results".

XML file format:

```xml
<comboOptions>
    <option value="1" text="MAINTYPE 1: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION">
        <option value="NOT_REQ" text="SUBTYPE NOT REQUIRED (NOT_REQ)"/>
    </option>
    <option value="13" text="MAINTYPE 2: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION">
        <option value="VALUE1" text="SUBTYPE 1: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION"/>
        <option value="VALUE2" text="SUBTYPE 2: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION"/>
    </option>
    <option value="11" text="MAINTYPE 5: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION">
        <option value="VALUE1" text="SUBTYPE 1: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION"/>
        <option value="VALUE2" text="SUBTYPE 2: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION"/>
        <option value="VALUE3" text="SUBTYPE 3: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION"/>
    </option>
<comboOptions>
```

My attempts so far:

```bsh
[xml]$XmlFIle = Get-Content C:\Path\to\file.xml

$RemoveList = @("MAINTYPE 1: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION", "MAINTYPE 5: SOME UNIQUE DESCRIPTION")

ForEach ($option in $XmlFIle.comboOptions.option)
{
  $RemoveList | Where-Object{ $_ -notcontains $option.text }
}

$XmlFIle.comboOptions.option | Foreach-Object { 
  $myobj1 = $_.text
  $RemoveList | Where-Object { $_ -notcontains $myobj1 }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you could just run `$x.combooptions.option.where({$_.text -in $removelist}).removeall()` to remove the attributes you don't need.

Comment: This `$XmlFile.comboOptions.option | Where-Object {$RemoveList -contains $_.text} | ForEach-Object {$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)}` should also do it

Comment: @Theo your solution works with one minor change: -contains to -notcontains.  Thank you!